# Excel Find & Replace Formula for Switching substrings

Tags: excel

I want to swich one character to another. For example: interchanging all 3s to 5s and all 5s to 3s how can i achieve this with find and replace methods, or any other solution?

Comment: Use `IF()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought would be that you'd need to use nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions. If you did a straight 5 to 3 and 3 to 5, everything would end up as a 5. The first `SUBSTITUTE` would need to change the 5 to a character that woudn't show up anywhere. For example below I used a pipe delimiter as the intermediate place holder:

A1 : 355783

B1: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,5,"|"),3,5),"|",3)`

Result: 533785

Comment: Thanks for the answer it solved my problem elegantly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
=IF(IF(ISERROR(FIND("3s",A1,1))=TRUE,0,1)=1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"3s","5s"),IF(IF(ISERROR(FIND("5s",A1,1))=TRUE,0,1)=1,SUBSTITUTE(A1,"5s","3s")))
```